# Mobile Number Verification during registration by message from api like that in "viber" for android

Tags: android, api, sms, message, verification

I have the url, username and password of my Message API. and i am a beginner. i have tried certain codes but it failed. i want the working code for integrating this api with the parameters i have and also a receiver code for reading the message that is received by the Message API.

the process is as follows..

1. during user registration the user enters a number.
2. the number is sent to the url of API and the user receives a message with a random code.
3. the application verifies if the random code is same as that which
   was sent.
4. if it is same the user gets registers and sees the application
   content.
5. this activity only happens one for registration.

Do help me i am in a serious confusion...thank you alot in advance

Comment: What is the problem that you're facing ?

Comment: is there any issue here,this is the requirement r8..

Comment: the thing is i dont have a proper code for it and i am very new to it to make my very own code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code which worked for me..

Here, I'm asking the user to enter the phone number once during installation and a random number is sent as an sms from his phone itself. This process will be done only once, ie for registration only(if the entered code and the random code sent is matched.if not, it will not be activated and again the registration screen is shown)..

Here is the code..

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.text.Html;
import android.text.InputType;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class SplashActivity extends Activity {
    private int splashTime = 3000;
    private Thread thread;
    private ProgressBar mSpinner;
    Boolean number_confirmation=false;
    String randomcode;
    String deviceimei;
    String phonenumber;
    String sent_code,activation;
    boolean isactivated;
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    TextView tv_loading;
    public EditText input;
    SharedPreferences wmbPreference1,wmbPreference2;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    RandomCodeGenerator rc;
    boolean isInternetPresent=false;
    AlertDialogManager alert;
    ConnectionDetector cd;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        try
        {
            alert=new AlertDialogManager();
            cd=new ConnectionDetector(SplashActivity.this);
            isInternetPresent = cd.isConnectingToInternet();
            if(isInternetPresent)
            {
                //wmbPreference for Shared Prefs that lasts forever
                wmbPreference1 = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);   
                //installsp for Shared Prefs that lasts only just once each time program is running
                wmbPreference2 =  getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("install_code_prefs", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);

                boolean isActivated=wmbPreference1.getBoolean("ISACTIVATED", false); 
                boolean isFirstRun = wmbPreference1.getBoolean("FIRSTRUN", true); 
                boolean isPhonenumberEntered=wmbPreference1.getBoolean("PHONENUMBERENTERED", false);
                number_confirmation=wmbPreference1.getBoolean("NUMBER_CONFIRMATION", false);
                deviceimei=wmbPreference1.getString("IMEI", "");

                if (isFirstRun||!isActivated)
                {
                    // Code to run once
                    //code to get next random number
                    rc=new RandomCodeGenerator();
                    //code to set wmbPreference with FIRSTRUN flag
                    editor = wmbPreference1.edit();
                    editor.putBoolean("FIRSTRUN", false);
                    editor.commit();
                    // Showing Alert Message
                    //code to create alert dialog
                    if(isPhonenumberEntered==false)
                        phonenumberDialog();
                    else
                        passwordDialog();
                }

                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);             
                if(isActivated)
                {       
                    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);     
                    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
                    mSpinner = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.Splash_ProgressBar);
                    tv_loading=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_loading);
                    mSpinner.setIndeterminate(true);
//                  runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
//                      
//                      @Override
//                      public void run() {
//                          // TODO Auto-generated method stub
//                          
//                      }
//                  });
                    thread = new Thread(runable);
                    thread.start(); 
                }
                else
                {
                    editor = wmbPreference2.edit();
                    editor.putBoolean("FRESHRUN", true);
                    editor.commit();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // Internet Connection is not present
                alert.showAlertDialog(SplashActivity.this, "xxxxxx",
                        "Please connect to working Internet connection", false);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Toast.makeText(SplashActivity.this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
    public Runnable runable = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {

                Thread.sleep(splashTime);

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        tv_loading.setText("Completing..");
                        mSpinner.setIndeterminate(true);
                    }
                });

                startActivity(new Intent(SplashActivity.this,HomeActivity.class));
                finish();


            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception


            }
        }
    };

    public void passwordDialog()
    {
        //code to create alert dialog
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(SplashActivity.this);
        alertDialog.setTitle("xxxxx");
        //alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.logo);
        // Setting Dialog Message
        alertDialog.setMessage(Html.fromHtml("<b>PASSWORD</b><br/>Enter 6 digit password sent to your phone"));

        input = new EditText(SplashActivity.this);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        input.setLayoutParams(lp);
        //      bt_resend=new Button(HomeActivity.this);
        //      bt_resend.setText("Resend");
        //      bt_resend.setLayoutParams(lp);
        alertDialog.setView(input);  
        //      alertDialog.setView(bt_resend);
        alertDialog.setCancelable(false);
        alertDialog.setNeutralButton("Resend", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                phonenumberDialog();
            }
        });
        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("YES",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {

                // Write your code here to execute after dialog

                deviceimei=getIMEI();
                checkPassword();
                saveIMEI();
//              Toast.makeText(SplashActivity.this,"IMEI:"+deviceimei, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });


        // Setting Negative "NO" Button
        alertDialog.setNegativeButton("NO",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                // code to execute after dialog
                dialog.cancel();

                //code to finish app
                finish();
            }
        });
        alertDialog.show();
    }
    public void phonenumberDialog()
    {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(SplashActivity.this);
        alertDialog.setTitle("xxxxx");
        alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.logo);
        // Setting Dialog Message
        alertDialog.setMessage(Html.fromHtml("<b>PHONE NUMBER</b><br/>Enter Your Phone Number for verification<br/><small>*standard SMS rates apply</small>"));
        input = new EditText(SplashActivity.this);
        input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        input.setLayoutParams(lp);
        alertDialog.setView(input);  
        alertDialog.setCancelable(false);
        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Next",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {

                // code to execute after dialog                     
                editor = wmbPreference1.edit();
                editor.putBoolean("PHONENUMBERENTERED", true);
                editor.commit();
                String mobno=input.getText().toString();

                //save phonenumber in shared preference
                editor = wmbPreference1.edit();
                editor.putString("PHONENUMBER", mobno);
                editor.commit();

                final String rnc=rc.nextId();
                randomcode=rnc;
                //code to set installsp with randomnumber code
                editor= wmbPreference2.edit();
                editor.putString("install_code", rnc);
                editor.commit();
                Log.d("rnc", rnc);
                try
                {
                    //code to send text message
                    SmsManager sm = SmsManager.getDefault();
                    sm.sendTextMessage(mobno, null,"xxxxx\nInstallation Password\n#####\n"+"6 digit Password: "+rnc+" " , null, null);

                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    //                  Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, "Please Enter Phone Number", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                }
                //code to create alert dialog
                passwordDialog();
            }
        });
        // Setting Negative "NO" Button
        alertDialog.setNegativeButton("SKIP",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                passwordDialog();
            }
        });
        alertDialog.show();
    }
    public String getIMEI()
    {
        TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        String imei=telephonyManager.getDeviceId();
        return imei;
    }
    public void checkPassword()
    {

        activation = input.getText().toString();
        SharedPreferences installsp = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("install_code_prefs", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
        sent_code=installsp.getString("install_code", null);
        phonenumber=wmbPreference1.getString("PHONENUMBER", "");


                                        new WebServiceBackgroundTask().execute(phonenumber,sent_code,deviceimei);
    }
    public void saveIMEI()
    {
        editor = wmbPreference1.edit();
        editor.putString("IMEI", deviceimei);
        editor.commit();
    }

    public class WebServiceBackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
        int i=0;
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(SplashActivity.this);
            progressDialog.setTitle("YATRAMiTR");
            progressDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.logo);
            progressDialog.setMessage(Html.fromHtml("<b>Password</b><br/>Validating Password..."));
            progressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
            progressDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            String resp="";
            if(activation.compareTo(sent_code)==0)
            {
                //              Toast.makeText(SplashActivity.this,"Password Matched", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                //code to set wmbPreference with ISACTIVATED flag

                editor=wmbPreference1.edit();
                editor.putString("PWD", sent_code);
                editor.commit();

                        isactivated=true;
                        editor = wmbPreference1.edit();
                        editor.putBoolean("ISACTIVATED", true);
                        editor.commit();
                        resp="success";
            }
            else
                isactivated=false;
            return resp;

        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            progressDialog.dismiss();
//          Toast.makeText(SplashActivity.this,"Sent code:"+sent_code, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//          Toast.makeText(SplashActivity.this,"Entered code:"+activation, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            if(result!="")
                Toast.makeText(SplashActivity.this, result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            if(isactivated)
            {
                //code to restart app
                Intent i = getBaseContext().getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage( getBaseContext().getPackageName() );
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                finish();
                startActivity(i);
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(SplashActivity.this,"Wrong Password!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent i = getBaseContext().getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage( getBaseContext().getPackageName() );
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                finish();
                startActivity(i);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Your `MainActivity.java` should be like this..

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 
        wmbPreference =  getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("install_code_prefs", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
        boolean freshrun=wmbPreference.getBoolean("FRESHRUN",true); 


        if(freshrun)
        {
            Intent intent=new Intent(HomeActivity.this,SplashActivity.class);
            finish();
            startActivity(intent);

            editor = wmbPreference.edit();
            editor.putBoolean("FRESHRUN", false);
            editor.commit();
        }
        else
        {

                  ////your normal code here

            }
```

The above code checks if the app is activated or not..if not, the itwill be redirected to the Splashscreen Activity.

Now the Randomcode class is as follows(RandomCodeGenerator.java)..

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.security.SecureRandom;

public class RandomCodeGenerator {


    private SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();

      public String nextId() {
        return new BigInteger(30, random).toString(32);
      }
    }
```

ConnectionDetector.java

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;

public class ConnectionDetector {

    private Context _context;

    public ConnectionDetector(Context context){
        this._context = context;
    }

    /**
     * Checking for all possible internet providers
     * **/
    public boolean isConnectingToInternet(){
        ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager) _context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
          if (connectivity != null)
          {
              NetworkInfo[] info = connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();
              if (info != null)
                  for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++)
                      if (info[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED)
                      {
                          return true;
                      }

          }
          return false;
    }
}
```

AletDialogManager.java

```
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;

public class AlertDialogManager {
    /**
     * Function to display simple Alert Dialog
     * @param context - application context
     * @param title - alert dialog title
     * @param message - alert message
     * @param status - success/failure (used to set icon)
     *               - pass null if you don't want icon
     * */




    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public void showAlertDialog(Context context, String title, String message,
            Boolean status) {
        AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();

        // Setting Dialog Title
        alertDialog.setTitle(title);

        // Setting Dialog Message
        alertDialog.setMessage(message);

        if(status != null)
            // Setting alert dialog icon
//            alertDialog.setIcon((status) ? R.drawable.success : R.drawable.fail);

        alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.logo);
        alertDialog.setCancelable(false);

        // Setting OK Button
        alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            }
        });

        // Showing Alert Message
        alertDialog.show();
    }
}
```

Try this and check if this was the one that was needed for you..Please do tell me if there are any errors..

Comment: Sir, i appreciate your answer but can i have a code where sms gateway is intergrated and i have to use the url and user name & password of the sms api to send a message and then verifies it by that random code send to his own number from the sms api. it is like in viber and some other apps which use message verification. Thanks for your support.

Comment: Also here the alertdialogmanager and connectiondetector cannot be resolved as a type.